Referencing colored item
I am trying to create an enumeration where the item numbers are colored blue. I followed this answer, and it works as expected.
However, I encountered an issue when referencing specific items. Ideally, I'd like the reference to inherit the color I’ve set for links (e.g., red), rather than the blue used for the item numbers. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work as intended in my implementation (see the example below).
Could someone help me figure out how to fix this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newenvironment{colenumerate}{%
    \begin{enumerate}[\color{blue}(a)]
}{%
    \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}
    Here is a list of useless items:
    
    \begin{colenumerate}
        \item\label{some_item} Some item.
        \item Another item.
    \end{colenumerate}
    
    Let us consider \ref{some_item}.
\end{document}

As you can see, item (a) I refer to is colored blue instead of red:


You can use label=\color{blue}(\alph*), ref=(\alph*):

Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newenvironment{colenumerate}{%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\color{blue}(\alph*), ref=(\alph*)]
}{%
    \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}
    Here is a list of useless items:
    
    \begin{colenumerate}
        \item\label{some_item} Some item.
        \item Another item.
    \end{colenumerate}
    
    Let us consider \ref{some_item}.
\end{document}


Strange, you've got three times "(a)", instead of a and b in the enumeration.

@KeksDose: Corrected. Thanks for letting me know.
